# How to simultaneously download webpages using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a web scraping application in Python. The website I am scraping has urls of the form `www.someurl.com/getPage?id=x` where `x` is a number identifying the page. Now, I am downloading all the pages using `urlretrieve`

Here is the basic form of my script:

```
for i in range(1,1001):
    urlretrieve('http://someurl.com/getPage?id='+str(i) , str(i)+".html)
```

Now, my question - is it possible to download the pages simultaneously? Because, here I am blocking the script and waiting for the page to download. Can I ask Python to open more than one connection to the server?

Comment: You could use threads https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/threading.html

Comment: @Paco, how many should I use?

Comment: look at libraries: requests, requests.futures

Comment: @Paco, can you provide a small example?

Comment: You should prob be aware that some servers don't "take too kindly" to you hammering them with requests...

Comment: @AbdAzrad that is not an issue here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getting some google searches concurrently in Python 2:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from urllib import urlretrieve

def loadpage(x):
    urlretrieve('http://google.com/search?q={}'.format(x), '{}.html'.format(x))

p = ThreadPool(10) # the max number of webpages to get at once
p.map(loadpage, range(50))
```

You could just as easily use Pool instead of ThreadPool. That would make it run on multiple processes/CPU cores. But since this is IO bound I think the concurrency that threading offers is enough.

Comment: erm, sorry i;m a bit of a newbie - what does p.map do?

Comment: The given function is applied to each element in the itertable. So it is like calling loadpage(0), loadpage(1), ..., loadpage(49). It is called on separate threads, up to 10 at once, since that is the size of the thread pool.

Comment: so p.map automatically takes values from `range` and supplies them to `loadpage` ?

Comment: Ah. this is perfect, exactly what I wanted

Comment: no problem, and you're right with your understanding of p.map

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot ask python to open more than one connection, you have to use either a framework for doing this or program a threaded application youself.

[scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is a framework for downloading multiple pages at the same time.

[twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) is a framework for threading, and it does handle multiple protocols. It is alot simpler to just use scrapy, but if you insist on building stuff yourself, this is probably what you want to use.

Answer (score 2):

You could use multi-threading to web scrape as it was used on the link [Threading](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/)

OR

you could check the simple example for threading on this [link](http://www.codingninja.co.uk/building-a-concurrent-web-scraper-with-python/).